# How to update Theia image with patches to avoid upgrading Theia version?

Tags: eclipse-che, theia

eclipse/che-theia image is based on a specific version of Theia. How to include changes to the current version when we can't wait for the next Theia release ?

Answer (score 0):

Patches are per version
let say you want to patch 0.3.12 version
you put patches in `dockerfiles/theia/src/patches/0.3.12` folder and name your patches like `001-this-is-my.patch` , `002-another.patch`

For `0.3.13`, patches will go in `dockerfiles/theia/src/patches/0.3.13`, etc